# Need to recall a TAG to refresh the DIV the TAG created with new DATA, how to do it?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a generated html page ("ContactMaster.html") from a view. ContactMaster.html  uses a **custom template tag** to create a FORM within a DIV.

- The *custom template tag* (%form% --- %endform%) creates a DIV that contains  an empty form generated from a model ..

  ```
  -  class PrefixForm(ModelForm)
         class Meta:
             model = Prefix
  ```
- The *custom template tag* uses the file  "formJson-reload.html" and renders the data provided (  PrefixForm, 'classDiv' , etc )

Now I want the FORM (within the DIV generated by the *custom template tag*) to load the data (Fill up the corresponding fields) for a particular PK. So I can edit it and save it later.

- How can I do that ? Any comments or suggestions are welcome. Thanks !!

  **Options:**

  1. I think with AJAX, I can retrieve the needed data for the form and load the fields of the form withe this data OR
  2. Somehow recall the *custome template tag* (%form% -- %endform%) and pass the Form with the needed data ( instance of the form with the PK )

Thanks for your time !!

---

*Here is more information:*

An example  of the use of the *custom template tag*

```
            {%form%}
            START_DICT
                {
                'classDiv' : 'container',
                'classDiv'  : 'module',
                'divId'     : 'Prefix',
                'title'     : 'Prefix JSON',
                'formId'    : 'PrefixForm',
                'classForm' : 'None',
                'idSubmit'  : 'SendPrefix',
                }
            END_DICT
            START_FORM
                PrefixForm
            END_FORM
            FILE:"formJson-reload.html"
            {%endform%}
```

An excerpt of the view that  creates the WHOLE web page that contains this *custom template tag*:

```
@login_required
def ContactMaster(request):
    Forms = ['Prefix',]
    dic_return = help_get_forms(Forms,request)

    return render_to_response('ContactMaster.html',dic_return,
       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

An excerpt of "formJson-reload.html":

```
        <div class="{{classDiv}}"  id="{{divId}}"  title="{{title}}">
            <form  id="{{formId}}" method="post" action="item_form"
                   {% if classForm != "None" %}
                        class="{{classForm}}>
                   {% else %}
                        >
                   {% endif %}
            <table id="T_{{formId}}">
                <tbody>
                    {%for field in set %}
                        {% if field.label != "Owner" %}
                            {% if field.label != "owner"  %}
                    <tr>  
                        <td>
                            {{field.label_tag}} :
                        </td> <td>  {{field}}
                         {% if field.field.required %}<em>*</em>{% endif %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}

                    {%endfor%}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" id="{{idSubmit}}" value="Add"
                   onclick="submit('{{formId}}');
                       return false;" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the page allready loaded and do not want to reload the compelete page, you will definitely need AJAX. That's exactly what the first A (asynchronous) of that abbreviation stands: loading content without reloading the complete page. As far as i can see you will have to extend your view as well. You can find a pretty good example for ajax and django in action here:
http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jul/02/django-and-ajax/
or here:
http://lethain.com/entry/2007/dec/11/two-faced-django-part-5-jquery-ajax/
These two articles should start you right of. Fight it :)

If you are just talking about populating the form with data from django while it is being generated from the template, i suppose you work through this article of the Django docs:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/

Comment: Thanks _@marue_ Your answer is more on the line of option 1. I could get with $.getJSON() the particular "data" (instance of the form for a PK )and then with  $("#T_{{formId}}").html(data) and have {{formId}} populated...Working on that now...  Regarding option 2...How can I recall the tag ( %form% -- %endform%) and pass to it new data (context) ?? Thanks

Comment: Probably the best thing you could do is create a custom templatetag that outputs the complete form. You can see here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/ how to do that. Then you could just create a template containing only the customtag, which would result in only the form being rendered. If you have that included in a <div id="the_form"> you could just get a new form with an ajax-get ($.get in jquery ie.) and replace the form with the results of that ajax-request. No need to worry about the overhead, if you get into performance trouble fix that later on.

Comment: Thanks _@marue_ I finally a view to return me the form for a particular pk. And with a  **_.html(data);_** where **_data_** is the form returned from the view I was able to update the form in the **DOM**. I will update later in the question with more info for other people´s reference